# Does Flash Builder 4 now use AIR 2?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, air2

I just got CS5 master suite which includes Flash Builder 4 and Flash CS5 Pro.

When I create a new AIR app in CS5 pro it says "AIR 2" but when I create a new AIR project in Flash Builder I do not see anything indicating that it is AIR 2 or 1.5?

Is there a way to tell which AIR runtime it is using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you'll have to download the SDK and st it up yourself; but Flash Builder should work fine:

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/AIR_2:Release_Notes

> How to overlay the Adobe AIR SDK for use with the Flex SDK
>
> 1. Copy the contents an existing Flex SDK folder to a new folder. For
>      example, in Flex Builder, copy the
>      following folder located at:
>            * Windows: c:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.2.0
>            * Mac OS: /Applications/Adobe Flex Builder
>      3/sdks/3.2.0
> 2. Download the appropriate AIR SDK file for your operating system and
>      save it to the root folder of the Flex
>      SDK.
>            * Windows: AIR20_win_sdk_XXXXXX.zip
>            * Mac OS: AIR20_mac_sdk_XXXXXX.tbz2
> 3. Extract the contents of the AIR SDK archive and overwrite the existing
>      SDK files in the copied folder.
>            * Windows: Right-click on the ZIP file and select "Extract All"
>      or use the decompression tool of your
>      choice.
>            * Mac OS: In Terminal, cd to the root folder of the Flex SDK and
>      run this command:
>            * tar jxvf AIR20_mac_sdk_XXXXXX.tbz2
>
>    ```
>      If you have trouble overwriting files due to file
>    ```
>
>    permissions, try this command 
>            sudo tar jxvf AIR20_mac_sdk_XXXXXX.tbz2
> 4. In Flex or Flash Builder, open the Properties dialog and choose the
>      Flex Compiler page
> 5. Click the Configure Flex SDKs... link
> 6. Add the combined Flex and AIR 2 SDK folder created above
> 7. Use this SDK for any projects accessing AIR 2 APIs.

To update this for the production release; go downlod your preferred version of the Flex SDK at http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads and download the AIR 2 SDK at http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=airsdk .

Overlay the two using the instructions above (1-3); then configure the new SDK in Flash Builder (also using the instructions above (4-7).

---

Update: Since my original post of this; Flex 4.1 SDK was released which includes the relevant AIR 2 bits.  [You can get it here](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex4sdk)

Comment: This is so annoying, Flash CS5 and FB4 came together in CS5 suite yet Flash CS5 uses AIR 2 and FB4 uses 1.5. You would think they would use the same runtime version. And adobe should release an update to add the support instead of making you go through the tedious process of adding all the correct files in the correct places.

Comment: Flash Builder 4 was released a handful of months before the release of the CS Suite.  I haven't done much AIR Development in a while, but I would expect that Adobe will eventually offer up an Easy way" to build AIR 2 apps from Flash Builder. Remember AIR 2 has only been out for a handful of days.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to use AIR 2 is to download a new version of the Flex framework. I've downloaded version 4.1.0.16076 from [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4) and it comes with AIR 2 already installed.

Today Adobe release the stable version of AIR 2 SDK so probably they come up with a new stable release of the Flex SDK.