# flex 4.5.1 with air 2.7 on ipad

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, ipad, air

I was reading that air 2.7 version should improve my application performance which is awesome.

Howeverrr , I do not understand what determines what air version is compiled with my application, if I upgrade the air version that is running on my dev machine will that make the change?

I was looking for a parameter in the flex project settings but all I can find there was the sdk to use with my app (4.5.1)

How do I export my app in a way that it will run on air 2.7 ???
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK determines which version of the AIR for iOS Packager is used when building your application.

In Flash Builder 4.5.1 (and Flex 4.5.1) the iOS emulator uses AIR 2.6; however the actual packager--when you export a release build / create the IPA--will use AIR 2.7 .

As long as you have Flash Builder 4.5.1 and are using the Flex 4.5.1 SDK; you're goign to have IPAs that use AIR 2.7.

There are ways to [overlay different AIR SDKs into different Flex SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040401/does-flash-builder-4-now-use-air-2/3040935#3040935), however in your case I do not think it is needed.